# (xcode) SAVE int value

Tags: xcode, save, int, counter

Hi everyone I'm trying to make an apps and in this apps there is a kind of counter to count each time I touch a button. 
When I touch the button, there is that:
NumberCount +1
TotalCount +1
text who show the number of NumberCount.

The number count value is when I'm using the counter, when I quit the page it starts again at zero. I'm showing in an other page TotalCount who's the number of total of time I touched the button but I want to save the value after I open the apps because when I quit the apps, the total count is back at zero. How can I save the TotalCount in the Apps and how can I load it automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `NSUserDefaults` and see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941008/what-is-the-correct-way-to-save-nsuserdefaults-when-my-app-is-terminated-on-ios

Comment: Or google "nsuserdefaults save when app closes"